# Creating a NetworkLoadBalancer with existing Elastic IPs

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm trying to set a pair of Elastic IPs as the public facing addresses for a NetworkLoadBalancer object and running into issues.  The `console.log("CFN NLB");` line in the code below never executes because the load balancer definition throws the following error:

```
There are no 'Public' subnet groups in this VPC. Available types:

Subprocess exited with error 1
```

I'm doing it this way because there's no high-level way to assign existing Elastic IPs to a load balancer without using the Cfn escape hatch as discussed [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/9696).

If I enable the commented code in the NetworkLoadBalancer definition, the stack synths successfully but then I get the following when deploying:

```
You can specify either subnets or subnet mappings, not both (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancing; Status Code: 400; E
rror Code: ValidationError; Request ID: e4b90830-xxxx-4f13-8777-bcf56946781a; Proxy: null)
```

Code:

```js
    const pubSubnet1ID = 'subnet-xxxxxfa6d669cd496';
    const pubSubnet2ID = 'subnet-xxxxxbaf8d2d77afb';
    const pubSubnet1 = Subnet.fromSubnetId(this, 'pubSubnet1', pubSubnet1ID);
    const pubSubnet2 = Subnet.fromSubnetId(this, 'pubSubnet2', pubSubnet2ID);

    console.log("Tagging.");
    Tags.of(pubSubnet1).add('aws-cdk:subnet-type', 'Public');
    Tags.of(pubSubnet2).add('aws-cdk:subnet-type', 'Public');
    
    console.log("Load Balancer...");
    this.loadBalancer = new NetworkLoadBalancer(this, 'dnsLB', {
      vpc: assets.vpc,
      internetFacing: true,
      crossZoneEnabled: true,
      // vpcSubnets: {
      //   subnets: [pubSubnet1, pubSubnet2],
      // },
    });

    console.log("CFN NLB");
    this.cfnNLB = this.loadBalancer.node.defaultChild as CfnLoadBalancer;

    console.log("Mappings");
    const subnetMapping1: CfnLoadBalancer.SubnetMappingProperty = {
      subnetId: pubSubnet1ID,
      allocationId: assets.elasticIp1.attrAllocationId,
    }
    const subnetMapping2: CfnLoadBalancer.SubnetMappingProperty = {
      subnetId: pubSubnet2ID,
      allocationId: assets.elasticIp2.attrAllocationId,
    }

    console.log("Mapping assignment");
    this.cfnNLB.subnetMappings = [subnetMapping1, subnetMapping2];
```

I've found references to CDK wanting a tag of `aws-cdk:subnet-type` with a value of `Public` and added that tag to our public subnets (both manually and programmatically), but the error remains unchanged.

Comment: Are you sure these two `Subnet` are part of your `assets.vpc`?

Comment: I found the solution.  Uncommenting the `vpcSubnets:` part of the loadBalancer definition allowed me to get past the first error message.  To get around the "You can specify either subnets or subnet mappings, not both" message, I added

`this.cfnNLB.addDeletionOverride('Properties.Subnets');`

before setting the `subnetMappings` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  Uncommenting the `vpcSubnets:` part of the loadBalancer definition allowed me to get past the first error message.  To get around the "You can specify either subnets or subnet mappings, not both" message, I added

`this.cfnNLB.addDeletionOverride('Properties.Subnets');`

before setting the `subnetMappings` attribute.